# Access results outer helper in inner helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars and I want to return array in first helper and then use it in next helper like this:

```
{{#tags postId}}
 {{#each this}}
   <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
 {{/each}}
{{/tags}}
```

Is it possible ? How can I implement this ? I've tried to use function

```
function(content, opt) {
  var tags = [{id:1, title: 'tag1'}, {id:2, title: 'tag2'}];
  opt.fn(tags);
};
```

but I cant access tags array in next helper. I know that I can build HTML in first function, but I want to keep my html code separate from the js-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the content of the block helper:

```
function(content, opt) {
  var tags = [{id:1, title: 'tag1'}, {id:2, title: 'tag2'}];
  return opt.fn(tags);
};
```

Comment: Oh, it was so simple. Thank you so much.